# Mass update / import bulk email preferences?

Tags: email, import, data-import

So - here is the deal - we have an excel sheet with hundreds of contacts - with which email they would like set as bulk mail. While doing an import, I see no option to indicate bulk mail preferences - any suggestions?

Civi 5.10, Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

The API CSV import extension using the email entity has a way to import these.[image]

It looks like you can match on external ID.

Comment: So I have the CiviCRM contact ID - I want to mark an email as use for bulk mail - so I have selected Email Contact (Match using external identifier) and chose the column with the Contact ID - and I chose the column with the email to match with Use for bulk mail.  Then I get the error: Missing required field(s) : email

Comment: I do not know why contact ID field is not available. The actual email should use 'email' field and then it is '1" value for 'Use for bulk email'.